# Fetching Data From View takes too much time in Application

Tags: view, sql-server-2012

I Created a view by joining multiple Tables and also Uses a SubQuery.

and all the columns from view  are mapped to Aplication

In a view only 1000 Rows are there and it takes 2 min to run

Issue:

In Application it takes 40 to 50 sec to fetch data from the View

Is the Database Issue or Network related issue please suggest me

Comment: No way that we can tell with this little information, but at 1000 rows, it *probably* is not the network.  Please post the query plan, the View code, and explain exactly what you are doing when "*it takes 2 min to run*", vs "*In Application it takes 40 to 50 sec*".  How are you running it in the first case?

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: when i execute  a command like (Select * from View_Name) it Takes 2 min to Execute